# PubsubIO write using Wait.on after PubsubIO read in streaming DF

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a streaming dataflow on GCP and I want to send the incoming message I read from pubusb to a different topic at the end of the flow - only after an element has been processed.

I'm using `Wait.on()`, and windowing my incoming messages to 10 seconds, but `wait.on` hangs and messages are being sent only after 10-15 min and I'm not sure why.

My dataflow looks somesthing like this:

```
 PCollection<String> request = pipeline
         .apply("Read From Subscription: " + inputTopicSubscription,
                 PubsubIO.readStrings()
                         .fromSubscription(inputTopicSubscription)
         )
         .apply("Split to windows", Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(10)))
                 .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO));

PCollection<MyProcessedObject> res = request
        .apply(...)
        .apply(...)
        .apply(...);

PCollection<String> pendingRequest = request.apply("Wait for processing", Wait.on(res));

outputTopics.forEach(topicName ->
                pendingRequest.apply("Write Results To Topic " + topicName, PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(topicName)));

pipeline.run();
```

I tried changing the duration, adding `AfterWatermark` triggering, but nothing helped.

Comment: Could the 10-15 minute delay be because of the processing on your objects? Fixed windows group elements based on their timestamps, but doesn't affect processing time, so the elements might just legitimately take 10-15 minutes to process.